# SharePoint permission list - contribute minus ability to edit home page

Tags: 2010, permissions

**Need:** SharePoint permission list - contribute minus the ability to edit page contents (insert/delete new  webparts). Also users in this group should be able to add/delete/update documents, create folders, add calender events.

What I have tried so far :

Copied contribute and created a custom permission level (custom sales)

**List Permissions (checked items)**

- Manage lists
- Add Items
- Edit Items
- View Items
- Create Alerts

**Site Permissions ( checked items)**

- View Pages
- Open

**Personal Permissions**
nothing is checked

Still, users in this groups can edit the landing page on the Sales sub-site

So

- Contoso  site collection ( contoso visitors -- restricted read)
- Sales   Site ( contoso visitors , Sales_custom contribute)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Put the home page into a document library, break permission inheritance for just that page and set it to read only for members who otherwise have contribute on the rest of the site.

Comment: Let me try that , Do I have to do that for each subsite eg Sales-CA(subsite)-North(subsite)

Comment: @ Teylyn I did try what you had suggested but I ran into issues , so I created a folder named it "sys" and then open SP designer and go to /Sitepages/home.aspx and copy it and past it in the "sys" folder and then right click "Home.aspx" in the sys folder and clicked on " Make This page HOME Page" , so now this new page is the landing page but I cannot control what kind of page that is " Page or published page , webpart page" and I cannot add any webprts to the page

Comment: Where did you create a folder? I did not suggest that. Create a library, select an appropriate default content type. Build the page and make it the home page. Don't let SharePoint dictate what page type your home page should be. If YOU want a wiki page, create a wiki page. If YOU want it to be a web part page, create a web part page. Don't try to move the default home page from the site root. That won't work. Create a new page and make that the home page.

Comment: Sorry I created a document library via the browser named it sys

Comment: OK, that should work. Create a new page in the document library. You can circumvent all details if you go Site Actions > Site Settings > More options > select Page > Select Web part page. Store the web part page in the "sys" library. Add all the content to it. Then use the ribbon tool to make it the home page or open the site in SPD, select the page and make it the home page. Copying the default home page will not work.

Comment: SO far I have a document library named sys and it has a page (landing.aspx) which is the home page. Security should be ready only for sys document library rite ?

Comment: Right. Make it read only for everyone, then only users with full access can change it.

Comment: Webpart page " type " is the only page type which lets me choose the folder , sys in this case , but page and publishing page does not let me choose the folder , also webpart page will not have the quick launch on the left..

Comment: You don't want to use a web part page, create a Wiki Page Library instead of a document library. Delete the two standard pages, create a new page, save it, make it the home page with the button on the Page ribbon.

Comment: thank you , its perfect , just to take this further is it posssible to have a page with various webparts like announcments and shared documents and only one person can add new announcments and everybody else can add new documents to shared documents

Comment: Of course. Just keep in mind that the permissions are set on the lists/libraries, not on the web parts in a page. If Joe can add announcements and Jane can add new docs, then they will be able to do so from the home page that has web parts for these lists.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues in that when a user has Contribute permissions at a site level, it gives them all sorts of power in some of the oddest places. For me the fix was simple... At the top site level, edit the permissions for each group (not the owner) to remove the Contribute level (thus making them read only to the entire site).

Then you go into each list that you want them to be able to add\edit and turn off Inher. and add back the "Contribute" level just for that list.

This worked great in SP 2010 however in 2013 it does create a bug in a BLOG post where even though the user can edit a post.. the edit menu does not show.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

**You're using the wrong approach.** Instead of creating a new permission level for the whole *site,* what you're actually trying to accomplish (preventing people from editing specific content) should be accomplished by customizing that *content's* permission settings.

You don't need to create a whole new library, nor create and set a new home page, as teylyn's answer suggests. *(While that approach may also work, it's a much more complicated solution than you need.)*

Just go to your existing home page, then in the ribbon's `Page` menu, in the `Manage` group, click `Page Permissions`. On the Page Permissions page, click `Stop Inheriting Permissions`. Then, for each group that has Contribute permissions at the site level (and that you don't want to be able to edit the home page), check the box next to that group and `Edit Permissions`† as needed.

Or, if you actually want to prevent editing on *all* pages (the question title implies only home page), instead of using the `Page Permissions` button in the `Manage` group, use the `Library Permissions` button in the `Page Library` group.

---

†Or `Remove Permissions`, if all members of that group already have Read permissions through membership in another group, e.g., if an "Everyone" group has Read access to the site collection, you can remove the "Contoso Visitors" Contribute permission from the page and leave the "Everyone" Read permission in place.